# How can I modify regular expression

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

How can I modify regular expression so it can also accept + in my URL

see: http://awakeningwithin.simpletix.com/Search/Lorem+/
... error

if your remove the symbol:
http://awakeningwithin.simpletix.com/Search/Lorem/
... it works.

```
<rule name="RewriteSearch" stopProcessing="true"> 
    <match url="^Search/([_0-9a-z-]+)" /> 
    <action type="Rewrite" url="Search.aspx?term={R:1}" /> 
</rule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plus `+` character in URL means SPACE (the same as `%20`).

1. Based on the above try this one: `^search/([-_0-9a-z\+ ]+)`

2. If you see 404 error like this:

> **HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found**
>
> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that
>   contains a double escape sequence.

- go to IIS Manager, open **Request Filter** module (global .. or the one for specific site)
- choose **Edit Feature Settings** on side column (or via context menu)
- tick **Allow double escaping**

or use this code (place somewhere in **web.config** in website root folder):

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

If #1 does not work, then do #1 AND #2.

**TESTED on IIS 7.5 -- works fine**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 <match url="^Search/([_0-9a-z+-]+)" />
```

I simply added the `+` to the allowed characters. Note that the `-` must still be at the very end of the character set, since `z-+` has special meaning there (all characters between z and plus... whatever that means).

Answer (score 0):

How about adding "+" to the list of acceptable chars:

```
([+_0-9a-z-]+)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is for sure correct extended regular expression. The problem must be somewhere else.